# Creating Multiple Iframes one by one

Tags: javascript, iframe

How i can load multiple iframes one by one?

DadosDashboard is a json with : Posicao=number; objeto=url/src;

```
$(this.DadosDashboard).each(function(index, el) {

        if (document.getElementById("ContainerGraficosAdd" + el.Posicao) != null) {
            document.getElementById("ContainerGraficosAdd" + el.Posicao).innerHTML = '<iframe width="100%" height="100%" id="iframe' + el.Posicao + '" class="iframe" scrolling="no" src="el.Objeto.toLowerCase()" frameborder="0" ></iframe>';
        }
    });
```

On this way it's loading all one time.

Comment: What do you mean one by one? Any time interval?

Comment: Ex: my page has 10 iframes with graphics, it needs to load all to appear something on the screen, I would like to load one by one to show up gradually ..

Answer (score 1):

You can to use `setTimeout` and increase the time delay with each iteration of `.each` (`index * 500` will separate the creation of each `iframe` by 500ms).

```
$(this.DadosDashboard).each(function(index, el) {
    if (document.getElementById("ContainerGraficosAdd" + el.Posicao) != null) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById("ContainerGraficosAdd" + el.Posicao).innerHTML = '<iframe width="100%" height="100%" id="iframe' + el.Posicao + '" class="iframe" scrolling="no" src="el.Objeto.toLowerCase()" frameborder="0" ></iframe>';
      }, index * 500)
    }
});
```

Comment: I would like to fire another iframe only when the previous one has completed, but I will test your suggestion then come back. Tanks

Answer (score 1):

I make different, I create "iframe.addEventListener('load', function(){}" on each iframe, this call on finished loading, so i call/create the next iframe inside this... this can be usefull to anybody that needs call multiple iframes one by one...

```
  this.renderComponents = function(srcativo, posicao, index){

  if (document.getElementById("ContainerGraficosAdd" + posicao) == null) {
    return;
  }
   document.getElementById("ContainerGraficosAdd"+posicao).innerHTML = '<iframe onload="' + _mthis.me() + '.setIframeHeight(iframe' + posicao + ')" width="100%" height="100%" id="iframe' + posicao + '" class="iframe" scrolling="no" src="' + srcativo.toLowerCase() + '" frameborder="0" ></iframe>';
var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe"+posicao);

    iframe.addEventListener('load', function(){
    index = index+1;
  typeof(some_variable) !== "undefined" && some_variable !== null
    if(_mthis.DadosDashboard[index]  === undefined || _mthis.DadosDashboard[index]==null){
   return;
  }
  srcativo = _mthis.DadosDashboard[index].Objeto;
  posicao = _mthis.DadosDashboard[index].Posicao;
  _mthis.renderComponents(srcativo,posicao,index);});}
```